# Django app does not load images from AWS bucket's media folder

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, django-oscar, django-storage

I'm using `django-oscar`,and wanted to serve my static files with AWS S3.
To config my s3 bucket I've created a module called `aws` with `conf.py` and `utils.py` files.

On my website when I upload an image to the product it gets uploaded well with the correct path to my aws s3 bucket, but then after very short time the path changes from `https://mybucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/media/cache/..../image.jpg` to `https://mybucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/cache/..../image.jpg`

The images are in the `media` folder in my bucket.

I'm hosting my web app on heroku, the static files are served correctly but the issue happen in media folder.

Here is my code -

#### utils.py file

```
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage

StaticRootS3BotoStorage = lambda: S3Boto3Storage(location='static')
MediaRootS3BotoStorage  = lambda: S3Boto3Storage(location='media')
```

as `static` and `media` are the folders on my s3 bucket

#### conf.py

```
import datetime

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "xxx"
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "yyy"

AWS_PRELOAD_METADATA = True
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None 

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 
'myproject.aws.utils.MediaRootS3BotoStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 
'myproject.aws.utils.StaticRootS3BotoStorage'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'mybucket-name'
S3DIRECT_REGION = 'us-east-2'
S3_URL = '//%s.s3.amazonaws.com/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
MEDIA_URL = '//%s.s3.amazonaws.com/media/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_URL
STATIC_URL = S3_URL + 'static/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + 'admin/'

two_months = datetime.timedelta(days=61)
date_two_months_later = datetime.date.today() + two_months
expires = date_two_months_later.strftime("%A, %d %B %Y 20:00:00 
GMT")

AWS_HEADERS = { 
    'Expires': expires,
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=%d' % 
    (int(two_months.total_seconds()), ),
}
```

and my settings.py I added this

```
from myproject.aws.conf import *
```

What should I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file storage system configured for your Django app should be a class that implements `django.core.files.storage.Storage` <sup>[[1]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-file-storage/#writing-a-custom-storage-system)</sup>

`storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage` already implements this storage interface. <sup>[[2]](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/blob/1.7.1/storages/backends/s3boto.py#L186)</sup>

Setting `StaticRootS3BotoStorage` in `utils.py` to a `lambda`, the `Storage` system is instantiated lazily with the proper `location` value; but the `location` attribute in the storage class itself is never changes. <sup>[[3]](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/blob/1.7.1/storages/backends/s3boto.py#L216)</sup>

```
location = setting('AWS_LOCATION', '')
```

Django clears properties of storage instance when the project settings changes. <sup>[[4]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.1.4/django/core/files/storage.py#L180)</sup> So that when the `location` attribute is resolved on the storage system, it effectively looks up the class attribute one (`location` value is shown in above snippet) because `location` attribute is missing in the instance.

This situation can be solved by subclassing `storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage` instead. This guarantees that `location` value never changes regardless of changes to project settings.

```
class StaticRootS3BotoStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = 'static'

class MediaRootS3BotoStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = 'media'
```