# Django admin able to upload images to S3 bucket but doesn't load on template

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I was able to upload images to my s3 bucket via django admin however, the images do not load on the HTML page. I followed the documentation and checked some tutorials and other solutions but none worked so far. I tried adding the region name of my s3 bucket but this didnt worked either. I also tried making the bucket public but to no avail.

This is my settings.py:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_S3_REGION_NAME')

AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

Upon inspecting element and viewing the image, I am greeted with this error:

[image: error]

this lead me to the trying out making the bucket public and configuring utils.py (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53976351/9615990) which didnt work.

Comment: Try setting `AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION` to `s3v4`

Comment: Thanks a lot! been at this for a while and this solved my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to OP's feedback, setting `AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION` to `s3v4` should work.